How to extract required bit fields from 32 bit variable in Trace32
I want to extract bit fields 4 to 7 from READ_DATA variable.
Below cmm script I tried, but not working.
can some one help with working cmm script to extract bit fields in variable and to check a particular bit in variable is set or not.
&READ_DATA=Data.Long(A:0x12345678)
&MY_DATA=&READ_DATA & 0xF0 ; Bitwise AND not working


Expressions in TRACE32 scripts and commands may not contain spaces, because spaces are the argument separators for commands.
Thus, this should work:
&READ_DATA=Data.Long(A:0x12345678)
&MY_DATA=&READ_DATA&0xF0 ; Bitwise AND should work that way

Or in a single line:
&MY_DATA=Data.Long(A:0x12345678)&0xF0

